# How to tidy up a curl output and make it throw errors inside of Jenkins job?

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins, wget

I use curl commands in my jenkins jobs and I have some questions about them. I have a command like this. Here a get a json object, parse it and put the result to array "fileslist"

```
 fileslist=($(curl -u user:password -X POST -k http://server:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"type\" : \"folder\", \"repo\" : \"${REPOSITORY}\", \"path\" : \".\", \"name\" : {\"\$nmatch\" : \"\.\"}, \"modified\" : {\"\$lt\" : \"$borderdate\"}  })" | jq --raw-output  '.results | .[] | .name'))
```

1. When I use it, I have this information in my output , that I don't really want to see.

.

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

100  1196  100  1052  100   144   227k  31858 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1027k
```

I can use **--silent** option, but it makes silent all the output, so it doesn't match with **--fail** option. What I need is to see in my log only information about **errors**, that occurred during the curl command.

2. I want the command above (if something goes wrong) write a error and **STOP a Jenkins job**. When I use **--fail** option, it just writes to the output about a error and my script continues. You can tell me to use Parse Input Plugin, but it is not what I want: It marks a build as "failed build" AFTER the script finished it's work, but I want to make it stop immediately.
3. The same questions about wget command.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: not in a place to test, but i'm 60% confident that `--silent` won't affect `--fail`, since fail just checks http status. try making `curl --silent --fail http://httpstat.us/500 > /dev/null` the first line of your script (this definitely fails for me).